# Как выбирать объекты из массива с определёнными условиями C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно выбрать объекты из массива у которых работает определённое условие. Как это сделать в C#? 
P.S. (Unity)

Comment: Какое условие, что за объекты, какой именно массив, что пробовали, что не получилось? Без подробностей, могу ответить только: да, сделать можно.

Comment: `var результат = мои_объекты.where(условие).ToArray();`